# What is PV cut-off for a 100 A (12 V) lead-acid battery?

Tags: battery-charging, lead-acid

I have a 100 A lead-acid battery and it is charged by a solor controller charger.

The charger remains on after crossing 14.4 V. Is this harmful for battery life? If it is dangerous, what is the PV cut-off to charge a 100 A battery fully?

Battery picture:
[image]

Solor charger picture:
[image]

Comment: There is an image upload button on the editor toolbar that embeds the image in your post.

Comment: The display shows 13.4V - not 14.4V.

Comment: I tried to improve the language in your question, but can you please take a look at your last question and re-formulate it? Thanks?

Answer (score 1):

Overcharging is harmful for almost any kind of batteries. It damages the electrode plates. The battery life decreases drastically.

The PV cut-off should be at 13.2V. You can use 13.8V cut-off,but 13.2V cut-off will increase the battery life.

Comment: Does 13.2 cutt off charged battery fully?

Comment: Can use of battery during charging decreases battery's life?

Comment: 13.2V is a bit low - I would expect something closer to a 13.8V float voltage.

Comment: If the battery's open-circuit voltage(OCV) (at fully charged condition) is greater than 13.2V, then the cut-off voltage should be increased. It should be above that OCV.

Using battery during charging causes overheating of  the battery, and decreases the life.

After fully charged, the battery should be Trickle Charged. It keeps the plates active and increases the life.

Answer (score 1):

Overcharging a lead-acid battery will overheat it and cause it to eventually lose its electrolyte through excessive gassing.

What should happen is your charge controller should switch to a ‘topping’ or ‘float’ charge when full charge is reached.

More here: https://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/charging_the_lead_acid_battery

They give a range of 2.3 to 2.45V per cell - 13.8 to 14.7V for a ‘12V’ battery. Check with the battery manufacturer for their recommended value.